# What was Keefe making/building before vandalizing Superman's statue?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice

In the Ultimate Edition, before [Keefe](https://dcextendeduniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Wallace_Keefe) went to vandalize Superman's statue and then got arrested (around the 34 min mark), he was shown to be [making/building something using ropes, cans, duct tape](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MrlPoDH2sWw&feature=youtu.be&t=9), what was that?

[image: Keefe constructing something]

Nothing in the statue scene showed that stuff, apart from *one* spray can, which ought get the job done once he free climbed the statue.

Comment: Possibly some sort of bandoleer to hold several cans of paint, or a device to help him scale the statue?